# Null pointer exception on doing webview.loadUrl()

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I've been getting this error in my developer portal. I'm not sure why. Stack trace tracks back into some internal function call inside WebView object.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrlImpl(WebView.java:3008)
at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrlImpl(WebView.java:3047)
at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:3040)
at com.myapp.android.PreviewActivity.notifyJS(PreviewActivity.java:175)
at com.myapp.android.PreviewActivity.access$14(PreviewActivity.java:174)
at com.myapp.android.PreviewActivity$ActionBarItemClickListener.onClick(PreviewActivity.java:901)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my code `at com.myapp.android.PreviewActivity.notifyJS(PreviewActivity.java:175)`, there is this line 
`webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.onClick('" + action + "');");`

I'm actually invoking a javascript call from my java code. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you show some more code. Have you enabled javascript? Is there any page loaded, or are you trying to inject JS to an empty page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself. If `webView.destroy()` has already been called then calling `webView.loadUrl()` will cause this exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your webview is null. Did you call findView before?

Comment: I'm already checking `if(webView == null)` before invoking this. I'm sure webView is null.

Comment: Sorry. that was a typo. I'm sure webView is not null.

Comment: I revoked that comment ;-) You can do that with your first too. Well even if action is null that should work... By the way i'm not sure if you can execute javascript like this. Is JavaScript enabled in your webview?